# Array resetting back to empty Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

For some Reason, when I run this code, the data array always has something in it, even the line before if[data][index][numbercheck], but for some reason on the exact line it says list index out of range, and the vs code debugger shows that the array data is empty. I am unsure of why this is happening. Appreciate any help

```
data = ["111110110111","100111000111","011101111101","011011010010","001010001010","111101001001","010001110011","100001001111","110101010000","100001100010","000011000100","111101000101","100100100110","100000011111","101101111101","100000011110","001110101111","101011101011","110011000001","010100011110","100011000011","001000101001","101110010110","101110010100","110000001101","010001010101","110000010010","111011101100","101111011100","101000010111","011000011001","110011110010","110100011010","110110010011","001110001100","011011001100","000011101111","111010101001","000101001000","000010111111","110100100111","011000101000","101011001101","000110110110","010101001111","010011010110","101111100001","000111101100","000000101110","101110001111","010000001101","011111010011","101100011111","011011000000","110000010111","001011010010","101111100000","101010000010","011101101010","110010000111","011110011111","110000010110","011110101000","111001011000","111010011100","011111000101","011111110100","111101101010","111101101001","011011110011","100110100010","100000110000","010001010011","100110111000","101010110100","011011011010","010100100000","011110011100","110101000001","001010111101","011110011000","001101101001","010011001110","100000100111","000100101011","110000000010","100011101011","100101010010","001010100111","001111011100","010111100101","000111000000","010001011101","100111001001","111100010101","000110011000","000010101001","110001110101","011101000110","011101111011","110100011101","011001100010","011011010100","001110111101","000100110001","100100000000","010001110010","110010010100","010100111011","111010010100","010010111010","011001100000","110101110111","001111100101","001011100000","010011001000","010011011100","000000111001","010101110000","001100011100","000010110011","111000101010","100000010010","001001011101","011100100001","110111101000","101110001001","001011000110","100110011010","101010000111","110110000110","001100101101","000000001011","110001110011","010001100111","010100011111","000000010001","001100110011","011010011110","101100111101","000111000110","101000111010","011011001011","011111000000","111011010110","000011001111","101100100000","100111010000","010000001010","001010001011","000011000010","111001110100","000011000011","000001101001","000000010010","100100010001","011010010111","110111011010","101101001110","001110010110","010100110001","101101010100","000000111100","110011111110","000010100101","100111010111","110111101111","111010011000","110000111100","101001011100","101000100101","100010001110","101111001100","101100111000","000100000110","001100100100","101011011011","111010010101","100011100101","001100000111","100111000001","010001011010","101101110100","100011011110","110001110000","111100101000","100111111011","110000101010","101100110100","001001000001","110100011100","010111110001","110111101010","100001110010","100000000011","000111100001","111010011011","010101011110","001000001101","010111010101","100100011000","111000110010","110001110100","111001101000","110000111110","010111001100","011101110011","101001101011","011011110000","000111010010","110101010111","011101000101","000100100101","011100011101","010000100100","000101111011","110111010010","110111100010","000110111100","011011010011","111111111011","001111000101","111110010110","010000011011","111110011101","100111101100","001000100011","111010000010","001001001100","010000010111","101010100011","111110010000","110100100001","001111000010","110010000000","111110110001","100001101110","101011010101","111100100011","001111000000","101111111011","001001010101","001110111000","101010001001","110111000000","010101110011","001110101110","000011010101","000110111011","000010001000","100000100011","001001001001","011101111111","100101100101","010011101110","101000101100","110011000101","001101111000","000001011000","010100100110","111011001000","110110010111","001000001011","111000101001","011010011100","111011010011","011001101111","011000111111","010100000000","000111010101","101111011010","000100011111","011000000100","101111110010","111110001100","101111111000","111000001101","100000001101","100011110001","100111110100","010100000111","000000010000","010110011001","111001100001","110001011011","010101100011","110011011010","110001011000","110111010011","101000011110","111100011111","101011000111","101000011001","000100000000","010111000011","110001000100","001010011010","010010011000","110100001000","010000101010","111110000001","110101000000","000001110101","000010101101","010100001111","010110100010","011111110111","111000001000","000110001010","000010100011","011110101001","000101000100","100101110011","111110011100","011101001010","001001001110","110101111111","000101011100","001100110111","010010000010","000111010111","111100001110","011110110011","110110000010","101110011111","100101011001","111001111111","111010110110","110110011000","110110111010","100100111010","001010101011","100011001000","101011101010","111100111110","100010101000","011011111001","010111111110","111111011010","100111110000","100100100011","011101011100","011101011011","010001000110","011100010100","110111110000","110110101101","110001001001","110101011011","101101100011","101101010000","111011001111","100111100100","100110000000","100011011010","010100000001","001100011101","010011100011","000101011111","000111010011","001100110101","011011001110","101111000100","111110111101","111111000100","001101111101","001111111111","110101001101","011111110001","111001010001","001000110001","010010110111","000111111111","000001011010","100101101110","100001111100","110110010000","110110101100","010110101011","011111101010","001110101010","001111001101","000001101010","000100111100","101111100100","000010011110","100110010100","111101101110","100011111101","100111100001","011110100101","111101100110","101001111010","101001001010","001000101111","001111001011","101000100011","110100100110","110010101111","000001000001","001011010111","111101011011","000100000101","111001001101","110001101001","010111000001","101110101110","110100010011","001011110000","101000001011","011110111101","001010011111","001101110101","100001110110","111111111111","010011011011","000111101000","011011011000","000000001101","101111100101","000101101010","010111001000","011110110100","110100110010","000110011110","001011110100","001111101010","110100111101","010101011011","010101101011","101011100011","011110011010","111111001111","001100110010","101111101111","110010001001","101101100101","000111000101","000101010001","011100111110","001000001001","101100100010","001110010000","111110000010","110110001010","010001010110","001101010011","100011010111","100011000001","001111011011","001100001110","000110001100","000001101000","111101010111","010011100101","010010111001","011100111001","001000000111","010001000100","000110010000","000100011110","110110101111","100111111110","011111110101","100101100000","110101100011","010100100100","110011110100","001001101010","111110100111","000010101000","001010011001","101111100011","010110100001","100101001111","001010010010","101010101110","101101101010","011100010011","100001001101","001010011100","000010111101","001110100011","101000110000","111011001101","100100001010","111011111000","001100111111","010001111000","001010101111","101001110001","010111111101","010000011101","000011101010","001100111100","100110001110","001101001010","000001100001","011001001111","101011000011","110111101101","111101101100","001010110001","110101000110","010111010110","110100111010","101010011101","001000101110","111111011101","111100011100","010101110101","011100011011","111101100000","011100101111","110110100001","101010010111","100101101111","000001001000","111001000110","001101110001","100001000101","110110011100","100101110100","111010101110","100111110101","000010101011","011100110110","111110100110","111100000111","101111010111","100001000011","001011000000","100010010101","111000101101","101010100010","111110111000","000101000001","101001110110","110001101010","100011100111","100111001101","001100001001","010111110011","000011111101","010011100100","110101110011","101110101100","111100111000","101100011000","010101010000","001110000000","000000001100","010011111010","100101010100","010011110000","100011110000","000110011101","111111110010","100111100000","100001011110","111011000110","111001011011","110110100111","100101110001","111010100001","101101011000","100000100000","011000100110","100000100010","100010011100","001000011100","111111010010","000011011101","011001011110","000101100010","000100010000","110100111100","111011011001","100011010101","110010000100","001101100101","001001110100","101011011111","010000111000","111011100101","000010000100","010011110100","111000010101","000011111010","111100000001","011110010010","101111101100","000101011001","100110101100","000111110011","101110000011","011000101100","010001101011","111101000100","001010000110","111101111100","101000110001","010011010011","011111100111","110001011010","111110110011","110001011100","110010001011","110101101100","001001011110","110000010101","001100000010","111001010111","101001010010","101011101100","000110101011","101101101011","111100111011","111111000001","110100101010","010010110101","111101010101","000011100011","111000100100","000101001100","111100001100","110010001111","110010011001","110011111011","100101110010","100010010110","111001001000","010010010110","001000000110","111110011010","010100001100","111011011000","111011001110","100111010001","100110101000","000010100001","101111101001","100001100100","100000100100","010000100000","011111111000","111011111101","000001011001","000001011101","011000011111","111101111000","110000011110","011100110001","101001000001","111000111110","110111111101","101010001011","110101011001","001111100000","100100110000","100111000101","111011101111","010000010011","100101100111","100000110111","010101011000","111110110101","010000101111","110011001100","011010011011","000001100100","101110110110","010000101011","110101100001","000001011100","000100011101","100001000100","011110100001","010111001010","011000110111","011010001000","011000111001","010000010000","010001101100","010110111010","000000010110","101101111001","110000111111","111110010100","110110100010","101100001001","001000010011","011101101001","010111011010","001110110001","011110110111","111101100100","101011010111","011111011101","010000010101","111101001011","000110001000","010110101110","101001100100","101010010010","110010010000","101101001011","100110111001","010000000001","000111001011","011011101000","110110010100","110011111001","101110111010","111010001010","000010110010","000011000111","101000100111","101000000100","111110100000","110100110011","011100010000","100000001010","100000111101","111011010000","000001110001","111011000000","110100100100","010001001101","011100100100","011000101001","101011010110","001011001101","110100001101","011110001101","001010101110","011001000100","000011111000","111100001011","001111011001","010100000110","111001101110","001100011000","100001101001","101000101111","101100111011","100011111111","011100000100","000000001000","100100100010","111000110001","001100111110","001110011100","100010010111","100001000010","000111110100","010001010010","110111001011","010111110101","010110000010","110100010111","011000001110","011011011100","110010011010","101010101101","100111011111","111111101101","000010001001","000000110001","000100111011","111100110101","001011000100","111111110100","011001010111","000000000000","011100000011","000001000100","101000011100","101010011001","101011111000","011111001010","111110010101","001010110110","001011110110","110110110001","110100111111","000100110000","101000100001","001101000011","111110011110","000101101100","000011111011","100101100110","011101010111","101101000100","110000101110","110111111000","101111001011","111001101010","000010000110","001011011001","011010110010","010001110100","001011010000","101101000011","111111010100","011001110101","011011111000","010101010100","001000101100","111000000010","100000111011","100000000100","000000000110","100100111110","011110000110","100111001100","111010111000","001011010011","101100001101","110000001010","110101111100","101010111011","001100111101","101100111010","101010000011","011111001100","100011111110","010010011110","110001110110","010011011000","001001010100","101110001011","000101110101","101000000011","001011011110","101010000100","111111111001","101111001010","011010100101","011001001011","110110110101","010000111011","100001010011","010111100000","011000010100","001010011110","100101011101","001010000011","111011010010","000101111001","011011001000","101000010011","000111111001","110111010111","001100001011","001111001010","001110100110","101010011100","001100010110","101110111100","010110000011","000100101001","111111000010","000010110110","001111000110","010001011110","000101001010","011001100110","101010100000","010110110111","100010110010","101100001100","110010000001","101111101011","011100011001","010101000000","101010111010","110101110010","111101100001","111000100110","110101001001","110100110100","001110100010","001011011011","111011100110","010100111000","100100100111","011000000111","101110111000","011110000011","010011101011","101000001001","011101100100","000110110000","010100001010","011110010011","101010100110","101100110000","011110000100","111000010111","100100001000","000110001001","010000101100","010111101100","110101100100","100000111001","010101101001","101000001100","010100110011","100101000111","101001111111","000110011100","000101000110","001101000000","010101011101","110111011100","111010010110","111111000101","100111000110","100011001100","011000110100","011011011001","001000010111","100011101110","110011101111","001000110010","110010101110","001110011110","010110110100","000010011000","011111101000","100000001110","110100101110","001110110111","100110111010","101110101011","000110000001","010111110100","011111111011","110001100011","000101100100","100110011110","011000101010","011111100001","000000111110","010010110110","110101111110","101110011011","101001011000","000101010011","011110100000","001100010100","000011010010","001110100111","011010000000","001011100010","111100011000","100100100001","101010110101","100101010111","100010010100","111011011110","100001010101","011111111110","001011001001","100111010101","001000011010","100110111101","001111011110","101011100010","010110001111","100000101110","001000000011","111101100010","100110110011","100011001011","010101110110","000111111000","011110111111","100000010001","011001101101","100111001011","000010000111","110000101011","010000110101","101010111111","111110001110","111101110001","100100100000","000001110110","001101010000","111011100010","110001111110","100011001110","001001100001","000111111100","000100100000","000000101001","101011000001"]


numbercheck = 0

while len(data)>1:
    zerocount = 0
    onecount = 0
    ones = []
    zeros = []
    for index in range (0,len(data)):
        print(f"first data {data}")
        if data[index][numbercheck] == "0":
            zerocount +=1
            zeros.append(data[index])
        else:
            onecount +=1
            ones.append(data[index])
        if onecount <zerocount:
                data = ones
        else:
                data = zeros
        numbercheck +=1
        print(data)
        print(f"loop {numbercheck}")
```

Comment: In your first iteration in line `if onecount <zerocount:`, you're checking whether `onecount` is smaller than `zerocount` and if it is, you set `data` to `ones` which is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the first loop :

```
data = [given list]
numbercheck = 0
zerocount = 0
onecount = 0
ones = []
zeros = []
```

During the first loop :
Only `onecount` and `ones` changes to `1` and `['111110110111']` respectively, after application of the first `if-else`.
In the sequentially next `if-else`, `onecount(=1) > zerocount(=0)` and so the `else` condition is executed and `data` is set to the list `zeros`, which is empty.
This is why your array named `data` is becoming empty after the first iteration.

I can further help you if you specify what you are trying to do with the program i.e the question. This is all I can help you with for now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I am then unsure of why zeros is empty, as in the given set of data there are definitely numbers that begin with 0. Sorry if this is obvious, I am just a beginner

Comment: `zeros` is initially empty and after the first iteration, data becomes empty and zeros doesn't change. The error is caught immediately after the 2nd iteration begins and the program terminates there and then.

Comment: Sorry, my question is why zeros doesn't change, since there are many entries beginning with 0.

Comment: The first entry begins with 1, so it gets added to ones. By the 2nd iteration, data array is cleared and has no entries. So the program never reaches entries that begin with 0.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you so much for your help!